# conditional unset value in private array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, unset

I'm running a WordPress site and struggling with a private array, which looks like :

```
WP_Error Object
  (
    [errors:private] => Array
      (
        [user_login] => Array
          (
            [0] => ERREUR : cet identifiant existe déjà. 
          )
        [empty_email] => Array
          (
            [0] => ERREUR : veuillez saisir une adresse de messagerie.
          )
       )
    )
```

What I would like to achieve is to unset [empty_email] (only this one).

In previous versions of WP, the array was public and I used :

```
if ( !empty( $arg->errors['empty_email'] ) ) unset( $arg->errors['empty_email'] );
```

But it doesn't work any more.

Thanks for help.

Comment: private and protected variables are only accessible from within the object

Comment: Looking at [the Codex entry for WP_Error](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error), there's a `remove` method.  Does `$arg->remove('empty_email')` work?